# Gradle and Spring-bootRun can not find my class

Tags: java, spring-boot, gradle, dependencies

Having two Projects:

- Classic (Having main class)
- Advanced

Id like to have the Advanced to have all classes the `Classic` have. But as I run `Advanced/gradle bootRun` all the `Advanced` classes seems to be missing.

Advanced/src/main/java/foo/Bar.java:

```
package foo;
public class Bar{
   //empty
}
```

Classic/src/main/java/foo/Classic.java:

```
package foo;
public class Classic {
  public static void main(){
    try {
        Class.forName("foo.Bar");
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```

Exception:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: foo.Bar
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:602)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:340)
    at foo.Classic.main(Classic.java:14)
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: foo.Bar
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:602)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.classloader.RestartClassLoader.loadClass(RestartClassLoader.java:144)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:340)
    at foo.Classic.main(Classic.java:14)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49)
```

I have this in my Advanced/build.gradle:

```
...
dependencies{
  ...
  implementation project(':classic')
  ...
}
...
```

### Important info from Comments:

`Jacob G.`
I talked for awhile with OP in one of the chat rooms, and I've discovered a few things. When attempting to build the Advanced project with Gradle, it reports 50+ compilations errors regarding package not found:, referring to packages in the Classic project. Also, Classic and Advanced do not share a root project, so I have a feeling that attempting to depend on project(':classic') is futile. OP stated that commits can only be made to Advanced, so it may not be possible to fix the issue at all. For anyone curious, OP is also not using an IDE.

### Statement of respect

I made an edit to the question, I added an limitation. It was an very important edit that I can only commit changes in Advanced. Because of the fact that I have no experience in gradle I was not aware of the imporance of this additional information. I feel sorry for the late limitation, feel comfort for the courtesy and hope for understanding.

Comment: You are trying to load Advanced module class foo.Bar in Classic module. As per gradle config Classic module not depends on Advanced module it is in opposite way.

Comment: Could you share a minimal reproducible git ?

Comment: @MạnhQuyếtNguyễn Next weekend I could do that effort. I am not sure if I can construct this anyway because I am new to gradle.

Comment: @Grim Until that, I think a photo of structure / modules are great help. Are talking about a project with multi module (Advance/Classic) or two independent projects ?

Comment: @MạnhQuyếtNguyễn Can not send picture cause of security reasons. We are talking about a classic version and a advanced version that use the classic version.

Comment: I mean what's your project structure, does they are two modules in a multi-modules project (shared parent gradle.build) or independent (no related gradle.build?)

Comment: They are in different folders. In their folders are individual build.gradle-files. I neither find the word parent nor shared in those build.gradle-files.

Comment: I was trying to set up based on your question but I can't resolve classic project when running bootRun on advanced project - I was always getting `Project with path ':classic' could not be found in root project 'advanced'`. Is there some set up I may be missing ? I tried adding classic project in the settings.gradle but I would get `Could not determine the dependencies of task ':bootRun'.
> Could not resolve all task dependencies for configuration ':runtimeClasspath'.
   > Could not resolve project :classic.`

Comment: @Grim If not the project structure I would like you to share your gradle files as then we can identify your child and parent relation.

Comment: @SagarVeeram Indeed I have `settings.gradle` in Classic and Advanced. But the contents of the file in Advanced is pointing out that `This file was generated by the Gradle 'init' task.`.

Comment: @KunalVohra `Is there some set up I may be missing?`, well, I do not know. And do not try to register at gradle-support-pages because the last 100 questions have no answer. I am going to think that gradle is dead.

Comment: I'm trying to give the solution. Just clarify one thing are you trying to run Classic from Advanced

Comment: Do both projects should be gradle ?

Comment: @AnishB. Both gralde, unfortunately.

Comment: @AnishB. I do not like to run Classic having all the Classic classes and resources **only**. I like to run Advanced who has all Classic classes and all Classic resources and additionally have all the Advanced classes and Advanced resources.

Comment: How did you make the gradle locate the classic project from advanced when you run bootrun tasks ? In other word when you run bootrun tasks is the classic project built by gradle before it can be accessed in advanced project or do you build the classic manully before running advanced project ? I've no success ( this appears to be working for you as you can successfully invoke main class in classic from advanced ) in linking them without bringing them together under a parent project. For me even though I link them using project path gradle complains that there is no main class in advanced.

Comment: I talked for awhile with OP in one of the chat rooms, and I've discovered a few things. When attempting to build the `Advanced` project with Gradle, it reports 50+ compilations errors regarding `package not found:`, referring to packages in the `Classic` project. Also, `Classic` and `Advanced` do **not** share a root project, so I have a feeling that attempting to depend on `project(':classic')` is futile. OP stated that commits can only be made to `Advanced`, so it may not be possible to fix the issue at all. For anyone curious, OP is also not using an IDE.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you need is Gradle's [composite build](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/composite_builds.html). See my [POC project](https://github.com/mehmetsunkur/java-samples/tree/master/so/composite-build). 
The advanced project includes the classic project by [this line](https://github.com/mehmetsunkur/java-samples/blob/master/so/composite-build/advanced/settings.gradle#L11)

The advanced/App.java calls [classic.App.main](https://github.com/mehmetsunkur/java-samples/blob/master/so/composite-build/advanced/src/main/java/advanced/App.java#L8), And [the classic.App class](https://github.com/mehmetsunkur/java-samples/blob/master/so/composite-build/classic/src/main/java/classic/App.java#L11) can load foo.Bar from the advanced project. No need to do a commit to classic project.

Execute "gradlew run" in the advanced folder

to see how it works.

Comment: +1 : I didn't think about it before.  I think this solution can be excellent for the use case.  I also tried it   [in my POC repo](https://github.com/rondinif/gradle-multi-project-poc/tree/composite-build) and I confirm that works like a charm.

Answer (score 5):

As far as I could understand from the question we are dealing with a multiple project scenario. In this case the [multi project builds documentation](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/multi_project_builds.html) tells us that it is necessary to have a settings.gradle in the folder that contains the two projects:

[image]

then it is possible to run both the projects without `cd` change directory into the specific folder , but directly from the multi-project root by command: `gradle advanced:bootRun`

[image]

## EDIT according to *20200610 EDIT of the question* acknowledging the specification:  **commits can only be made to the `Advanced` project**.

we can still get a solution but in this scenario ( actually not a gradle multi-project)

- no need to have a `settings.gradle` at the parent directory level of `Advanced`; it satisfy the requirement of not being able to commit outside of `Advanced`
- it doesn't matter how it's built the `Classic` project, we don't care about it since we can't commit on it
- we can't use in `Advanced/build.gradle` the `implementation project(':classic')` as dependency since this works only in  *real gradle multi-project scenarios* ; in here we must use a  **file dependency** or another [type of dependecy](https://docs.gradle.org/5.2.1/userguide/dependency_types.html) available for the user's development environment.

[image]

In this case it is possible to run the Advanced project by `cd Advanced` then , from the *Advanced* directory run th command: `gradle bootRun`

[image: Limited-commit-to-advanced]

#### why it works ?

..In order to better understand how it works lets's inspect the
`SystemClassLoader`'s current paths by adding this lines of code in `Advanced/src/main/java/com/example/springboot/Application.java`

```java
ClassLoader cl = ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader();
URL[] urls = ((URLClassLoader)cl).getURLs();
for(URL url: urls){
    System.out.println(url.getFile());
}
```

the output is:

```
<multi-project-root>/Advanced/build/classes/java/main/
<multi-project-root>/Advanced/build/resources/main/
<multi-project-root>/Classic/build/libs/Classic-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
~/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework.boot/spring
... [suppressed many othe spring devtools and gradle related caches  ]
```

this allow both the Advanced and the Classic classes to find each others

#### source code of a proof of concempt

The [POC source-code new branch](https://github.com/rondinif/gradle-multi-project-poc/tree/limited-commit-to-advanced) has been updated accordingly

Comment: I hope I correctly interpreted the case, the source of my pic are  https://github.com/rondinif/gradle-multi-project-poc and they can be changed or forked  to adapt to different scenarios if some misunderstanding or for clarifications

Comment: Yes, but `settings.gradle` is not allwed to be on the same directory-level as Advanced and Classic since I am only commiting to contents of the Advanced-Directory.

Comment: @Grim https://github.com/rondinif/gradle-multi-project-poc/tree/limited-commit-to-advanced is a new branch that works by launching `gradle bootRun` from the `Advanced` folder; as a consequence of the modification of the question I also updated the answer

Comment:  I never ever seen such an engagement. I will wait for the branch to succeed. :)

Comment:  for any problem to operate with the POC or you want clarifications or ask for changes about the code it contains you can open an issue directly from this link: https://github.com/rondinif/gradle-multi-project-poc/issues/new

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same project structure as the one you have so by making below-mentioned changes it works fine for me :

1. Entry in build.gradle file

> compile project(':Classic')

2. Entry in settings.gradle

> ```
> include ':Classic'
> project(':Classic').projectDir = new File(settingsDir, '../../libs/Classic')
> ```

I hope this will work for you too and yes don't forget to rebuild your grade project after making these changes.

Comment: This does compile using `gradle bootRun`. Unfortunately the Class remains not-found in Classic.